# TwilioChatClient There is no callbacks from channelWithSidOrUniqueName:completion: and getLastWithCount:completion:

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, chat

we're stuck a bit with TwilioChatClient and can't sort out what's wrong. In some specific case there is no callback from some method.
For example:

```
twilioChatClient.channelsList()?.channel(withSidOrUniqueName: someSid, completion: { result, channel
    //  this block is never called
}
```

But we can fetch this channel using:

```
twilioChatClient.channelsList()?.subscribedChannels().first(where: { $0.sid == someSid || $0.uniqueName == someSid })
```

We send POST request to our server, where we create new channel. So the app get SID from response, and trying to connect to it
In the log after calling `twilioChatClient.channelsList()?.channel(withSidOrUniqueName: "CH4155de0b7d374f34b027b5885b207ff9", completion...` we see:

```
2021-01-13 18:15:51.167642+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x28119a700>>>> -      | Chat IPM | channels: [api] get channel CH4155de0b7d374f34b027b5885b207ff9
2021-01-13 18:15:51.167875+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x28119a700>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [Yq7OB] got channel from cache CH4155de0b7d374f34b027b5885b207ff9
2021-01-13 18:15:51.167928+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x28119a700>>>> -      | Chat IPM | channels: got from cache CH4155de0b7d374f34b027b5885b207ff9
```

So definitely Twilio found the channel, but why completion block is not called ?

After that we found workaround to get Channel directly from subscribedChannels() but we stuck with another issues with this channel (that was fetched from subscribedChannels())

If we try to fetch last message from channel using:

```
guard channel.status == .joined, channel.synchronizationStatus == .all else {
                    return
                }
channel.messages?.getLastWithCount(100, completion: { [weak self] resulte, twilioMessages in
     //  this block is never called also
})
```

It seems very strange... It happens only for new channels, if we restart app - everything is working as expected.

There is no errors in

```
- (void)chatClient:(nonnull TwilioChatClient *)client errorReceived:(nonnull TCHError *)error;
```

There is no updates here :

```
- (void)chatClient:(nonnull TwilioChatClient *)client connectionStateUpdated:(TCHClientConnectionState)state
```

OR

```
- (void)chatClient:(nonnull TwilioChatClient *)client synchronizationStatusUpdated:(TCHClientSynchronizationStatus)status;
```

We also check:
`chatClient.connectionState == .connected and chatClient.synchronizationStatus == .completed`
before calling `channel(withSidOrUniqueName:` and `getLastWithCount(`

We're using the latest version 4.0.2 and it works the same in 3.1.1 (Xcode 12.2)

A bit more information. We have controller that we use for showing AR (ARKit). And when the scene is recognized, twilio stops working.
On viewDidLoad we start the timer that each second perform two actions

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
guard currentIndex < sids.count else { return }
            guard isWorking == false else { return }
let sid = sids[currentIndex]
print("DEBUG: calling channelWithSidOrUniqueName \(sid)")
    chatClient.channelsList()?.channel(withSidOrUniqueName: sid, completion: { result, channel in
                print("DEBUG: get completion from channelWithSidOrUniqueName \(result.isSuccessful())")

                guard let channel = channel else { return }
                if channel.synchronizationStatus == .all {
                    print("DEBUG: synchronizationStatus == all")
                }
                if channel.status == .joined {
                    print("DEBUG: status == .joined")
                }
                lastChannel = channel
                print("DEBUG: calling getLastWithCount \(channel.sid)")
                channel.messages?.getLastWithCount(5, completion: { result, _ in
                    print("DEBUG: get completion from getLastWithCount \(channel.sid) \(result.isSuccessful())")
                    currentIndex += 1
                    isWorking = false
                    })
                })
```

And if everything is okay we see in the logs like

```
2021-01-14 13:12:47.435842+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | channels: [api] get user channels
DEBUG: calling channelWithSidOrUniqueName CH1425bfdb625945c1ab43bdb440e9ee2a
2021-01-14 13:12:47.437993+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | channels: [api] get channel CH1425bfdb625945c1ab43bdb440e9ee2a
DEBUG: get completion from channelWithSidOrUniqueName true
DEBUG: synchronizationStatus == all
DEBUG: status == .joined
DEBUG: calling getLastWithCount Optional("CH1425bfdb625945c1ab43bdb440e9ee2a")
2021-01-14 13:12:47.438580+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [9HU8c] channel: [api] get messages
2021-01-14 13:12:47.438727+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [9HU8c] messages: [api] getLastMessages, count 5
2021-01-14 13:12:47.438798+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 8564 | Sync TSCollectionItemQueryActivity(3) | constructed
2021-01-14 13:12:47.438865+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 8564 | Sync TSCollectionItemQueryActivity(3) | start 2999
2021-01-14 13:12:47.438977+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 2827 | Sync List | query page id: 2999
2021-01-14 13:12:47.439049+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Sync CoreDataActivity | query [1] /v3/Services/IS566142b988d74af6bba32abbdb4a7474/Lists/ES6bb26aae7efb48b49ec0b232e2b1ba65/Items?Order=desc
2021-01-14 13:12:47.439117+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Twilsock Message::makePayload | Payload size 0
2021-01-14 13:12:47.439234+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -  289 | Twilsock Client | sendUpstreamMessage, id = RQ8bfe33a7e9ac4507a060e1332a533eff
2021-01-14 13:12:47.648547+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 8564 | Sync TSCollectionItemQueryActivity(3) | response status 200 body 3349 bytes
2021-01-14 13:12:47.649263+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 8564 | Sync TSCollectionItemQueryActivity(3) | destructed
2021-01-14 13:12:47.649585+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [9HU8c] messages: query done, results count 3
DEBUG: get completion from getLastWithCount Optional("CH1425bfdb625945c1ab43bdb440e9ee2a") true
```

But after a while it stops working

```
2021-01-14 13:12:49.435863+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | channels: [api] get user channels
DEBUG: calling channelWithSidOrUniqueName CHa109c68be1454e5ca8bfffa3eedd37f2
2021-01-14 13:12:49.437479+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | channels: [api] get channel CHa109c68be1454e5ca8bfffa3eedd37f2
DEBUG: get completion from channelWithSidOrUniqueName true
DEBUG: synchronizationStatus == all
DEBUG: status == .joined
DEBUG: calling getLastWithCount Optional("CHa109c68be1454e5ca8bfffa3eedd37f2")
2021-01-14 13:12:49.438019+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [NRBeN] channel: [api] get messages
2021-01-14 13:12:49.438139+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [NRBeN] messages: [api] getLastMessages, count 5
2021-01-14 13:12:49.438248+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 8572 | Sync TSCollectionItemQueryActivity(3) | constructed
2021-01-14 13:12:49.438320+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 8572 | Sync TSCollectionItemQueryActivity(3) | start 3003
2021-01-14 13:12:49.438384+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 6750 | Sync List | query page id: 3003
2021-01-14 13:12:49.438451+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Sync CoreDataActivity | query [1] /v3/Services/IS566142b988d74af6bba32abbdb4a7474/Lists/ES0ca1135ad73e45d9b0f9e482ea1884b1/Items?Order=desc
2021-01-14 13:12:49.438551+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Twilsock Message::makePayload | Payload size 0
2021-01-14 13:12:49.438635+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -  289 | Twilsock Client | sendUpstreamMessage, id = RQc3dafd4ae4a546fa8cebee15567d1d14

2021-01-14 13:12:49.629690+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 8572 | Sync TSCollectionItemQueryActivity(3) | response status 200 body 3349 bytes
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630136+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> - 8572 | Sync TSCollectionItemQueryActivity(3) | destructed
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630233+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [NRBeN] messages: query done, results count 3
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630302+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [NRBeN] messages: range 0:2
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630368+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [JUbw4] message: StateNoState->StateNotInitialized
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630433+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [JUbw4] message: StateNotInitialized->StateInitialized
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630498+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [v2zHz] message: StateNoState->StateNotInitialized
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630562+0200  <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [v2zHz] message: StateNotInitialized->StateInitialized
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630797+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [nPcGj] message: StateNoState->StateNotInitialized
2021-01-14 13:12:49.630863+0200 <<<<TwilioChatClient: 0x282715790>>>> -      | Chat IPM | [nPcGj] message: StateNotInitialized->StateInitialized
```

And after that my method is waiting forever callback from getLastWithCount

I would be very grateful for any advice or suggestions

Comment: I was facing a similar issue where I was trying to call ```getLastWithCount``` and was waiting for callback forever because the client ```TCHClientSynchronizationStatus``` was not yet ```completed```. I had a different use case of auto logout where I was facing this problem. I resolved mine by shutting down client and reinitialising the same

Answer (score 0):

Twilio team confirmed that there is some issue when we use ARKit on iOS 14.3... 14.4
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-ios/issues/22